# Mapping Exception while serializing an object having a HashMap to JSON using Jackson

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I have a class that I am trying to serialize to JSON using Jackson:

```
class A {
    String someString;
    Map<String, Long> someMap;
}
```

I am serializing using the following code:

```
mapper.writeValueAsString(a);
```

where a is an instance of class A.

I am getting this exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Long (through reference chain ... java.util.HashMap)
```

I have tried enabling different Default Typing, but that has not helped.

Comment: I think your bug is elsewhere. Where is `someMap` populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your map contains `Double`s instead of `Long`s. Usually that's a result of ignoring warnings or using reflection. It's fairly easy to reproduce:

```
A a = new A();
a.someMap = new HashMap<>();
((Map)a.someMap).put("bar", 1.0);
new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(a);
```

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Long (through reference chain: A["someMap"]->java.util.HashMap["bar"])